# I use Include() in EF but show me error that my object reference is not set

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, entity-framework-4

I use the include Method in my asp.net mvc 2 project with EF 4.0

Here is my database structure.
**Contact** 
ContactID 
ContactName 
AddressID (FK) 
 
**Address** 
AddressID 
CodePostal 
Street

A contact can contain an address or not.
In some case, I dont want any address. In that case, the AddressID in the contact table will be null.

I try to do this

> _db.LocationContacts.Include("Contact.Address.City.Province.Country")

Thats give me an error if there is no address associate to the contact.
Is there a way to resolve that situation.

Thanks a lot.

This is the Error Message : System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line ...

```cs
var location = _db.LocationContacts
    .Include("Contact.Address.City.Province.Country").First();
```

... does not throw a `NullReferenceException`. It happens later when you access `location.Address.City` or some other property or method of `Address` and `Address` is null (which is expected for some locations because it is allowed to have NULL values).

You just need to check if `location.Address` is `null` or not:

```cs
if (location.Address != null)
{
    var city = location.Address.City; // OK
}
else
{
    // var city = location.Address.City; // Not OK
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are accssing the City which is under Address which is null !

Use it like this

```
var contacts=_db.LocationContacts.Include("Contact.Address").ToList();
```

That gives you contacts with Address.